# Error when pointing to a vector in my Inventory.h

Tags: c++, vector, header

Hey im trying to pint to my vector in inventory.h so that i have all of the vectors functionality in the main like push_back, pop etc....  Instead of typing out all the functions like pop,push i want a pointer to work but i have gotten errors.  Can anyone help me with this and tell me am i going on the  right path with this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

**Inventory.h**

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Inventory.h
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 
class Inventory 
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    string add(string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
    //vector<string> &GetContainer();
private:
    //Data members
   vector<string> inventory;
   vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
   vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    };


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

**inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
#include <string>


using namespace std;



Inventory::Inventory()
{

}

string Inventory :: add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}

void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
char input[80];
    cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(invent == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }


}
void Inventory:: displayInventory()
{
//vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "\n******Inventory******";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
inventory.GetContainer().push_back("Stone");
}
```

**Here are the errors:**

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > & __thiscall Inventory::GetContainer(void)" (?GetContainer@Inventory@@QAEAAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\MaroonedCA2\Main.obj  MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\Debug\MaroonedCA2.exe MaroonedCA2
```

Comment: why are you including vector and string in the.cpp file, as long as you include "inventory.h" then it will include vector and string.

Comment: @ForgiveMe but there is no loss from doing it. In fact, there is some gain: if for some reason the header stops needing `std::vector` and you remove the include from it, the .cpp file will still compile fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the implementation of `Inventors::GetContainer()` is missing. you must put that in the `.cpp` file, or inline in the `Inventory` class declaration.

In the `.cpp` file:

```
vector<string>& Inventory::GetContainer() { return inventory; }
```

Although beware, you are exposing a private data member. You might as well make the member public if you are going to do that. That way, you are under no illusion that you have some form of encapsulation.

Comment: Oh i see.  What exactly would i put in the .cpp.  because i dont actually need anything in it as it is a pointer.

Comment: I thought this would work: vector<string> Inventory::GetContainer()
{
}

Comment: @Pendo826 you return the vector by reference. I added the necessary line. Nothing happens by magic in C++, you have to be explicit most of the time.

Comment: Thanks man dunno how i forgot the .cpp.  Bit of lag lol.  But thanks.